# What is the ideal length of a method for you?

Tags: design, object-oriented, coding-style

In object-oriented programming, there is of course no exact rule on the maximum length of a method , but I still found these two quotes somewhat contradicting each other, so I would like to hear what you think.

In [*Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882), Robert Martin says:

> The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second
>   rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that. Functions
>   should not be 100 lines long. Functions should hardly ever be 20 lines
>   long.

and he gives an example from Java code he sees from Kent Beck:

> Every function in his program was just two, or three, or four lines
>   long. Each was transparently obvious. Each told a story. And each led
>   you to the next in a compelling order. That’s how short your functions
>   should be!

This sounds great, but on the other hand, in [*Code Complete*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670), Steve McConnell says something very different:

> The routine should be allowed to grow organically up to 100-200 lines,
>   decades of evidence say that routines of such length no more error
>   prone then shorter routines.

And he gives a reference to a study that says routines 65 lines or long are cheaper to develop.

So while there are diverging opinions about the matter, is there a functional best-practice for you?

Comment: Functions should be easy to understand. The length should follow from that, depending on circumstance.

Comment: I think the real limit is at 53 lines. With an average line size of 32.4 characters. Seriously, there's no definitive answer. A 100 line method can be very clear and maintainable, and a 4 line method can be a nightmare to understand. Generally though, long methods tend to have too many responsibilities, and be harder to understand and maintain than smaller ones. I would think in terms of responsibilities, and try to have a single responsibility per method.

Comment: There is a term in programming called “functional coherence”. The length of a function should be allowed to vary provided that its implementation still constitutes a single coherent unit of logic in your application. Arbitrarily splitting up functions to make them smaller is more likely to bloat your code and hurt maintainability.

Comment: And, if you want to limit your functions’ complexity, you should measure their [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), not their length. A `switch` statement with 100 `case` conditions is more maintainable than 10 levels of `if` statements nested within each other.

Comment: Apologies; I meant “functional [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)”, not coherence.

Comment: Bob Martin's approach is from 2008, Steve Mc Connell`s from 1993. They have different philosophies about what "good code" is, and IMHO Bob Martin tries to aquire a much higher level of code quality.

Comment: There's a link I love related to this question: https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop

Comment: 1/7th of a brain-full.

Comment: A function should be exactly as long as it needs to be, and no longer.

Comment: In Code Complete 2, Steve McConnell references 6 different studies and rewrites that quote. The new quote agrees more with Kent Beck and Robert Martin. He says, _"A large percentage of routines in object-oriented programs will be accessor routines, which will be very short. From time to time, a complex algorithm will lead to a longer routine, and in those circumstances, the routine should be allowed to grow organically up to 100-200 lines. (A line is a noncomment, nonblank line of source code.)"_

Comment: I disagree with the idea that the length of a method should contain all logic that that method is responsible for and nothing else, because that can still produce large methods.  I think the key factor is the maximum number of lines you can conceptually understand after having read the entire method, though it's also hard to gauge a number like that because it depends on the difficulty of what you're trying to do and whether you wrote it in a way that is easy to understand.

Comment: I find that the maximum level of nested control statements is also a good indicator of method complexity. If you have a lot of nested control statements in your method, it is likely to be too complex, and might benefit from being split up into several methods. I try to keep my nesting level below 3.

Comment: Related question: [Good practice class line count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086851/good-practice-class-line-count/1086865#1086865)

Comment: For me, it's usually up to 5 lines or so. More than that and I'm overwhelmed. :)

Comment: In his series Clean Coders; Uncle Bob mentions that functions should optimally have 4 lines of code. Actually, if you followed along his videos you will be very convinced.

Comment: @robertpateii Code complete 2 has the same first 4 studies compared against the original book, the 5th study doesn't appear in the list in the new version (removed in 2), the 6th study was rephrased but the same ("a recent study" to "another study" due to length of time between books I suppose) and the the discussion of the IBM beyond 500 lines study mentioned originally in a latter paragraph is now listed in the studies listed in Code Complete 2. I was worried when you said "6 _different_ studies" thinking you means 6 completely different/new studies :o)

Comment: Oh what a joy it is to keep jumping through countless little methods that are only ever called from one place anyways. And how I love to explore objects that are created to encapsulate data that is necessary to then call one method on that object to produce some output! Clean code is my favorite flavor and it's objectively the best approach since smart people wrote it in big books that are praised as must-reads for the modern software developer.

Comment: Ideal length is only one: **42**

Comment: Focus on real code quality and not on made-up metrics of people who want to sell a book, because they never created any meaningful software in their life. Programming and creating algorithms are arts. When art is restricted by stupid rules, it stops being an art. And then creativity and innovation die off, whether you like it or not. I've never met a guy or a company considering such restrictions and being able to create something impressive with their efforts. Let yourself free. If your code needs a refactoring somewhere, you'll know it in your gut and won't have to read a book to figure out.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Functions should normally be short, between 5-15 lines is my personal "rule of thumb" when coding in Java or C#. This is a good size for several reasons:

- It fits easily on your screen without scrolling
- It's about the conceptual size that you can hold in your head
- It's meaningful enough to require a function in its own right (as a standalone, meaningful chunk of logic)
- A function smaller than 5 lines is a hint that you are perhaps breaking the code up too much (which makes it harder to read / understand if you need to navigate between functions). Either that or your're forgetting your special cases / error handling!

But I don't think it is helpful to set an absolute rule, as there will always be valid exceptions / reasons to diverge from the rule:

- A one-line accessor function that performs a type cast is clearly acceptable in some situations.
- There are some very short but useful functions (e.g. swap as mentioned by user unknown) that clearly need less than 5 lines. Not a big deal, a few 3 line functions don't do any harm to your code base.
- A 100-line function that is a single large switch statement might be acceptable if it is extremely clear what is being done. This code can be conceptually very simple even if it requires a lot of lines to describe the different cases. Sometimes it is suggested that this should be refactored into separate classes and implemented using inheritance / polymorphism but IMHO this is taking OOP too far - I'd rather only have one big 40-way switch statement than 40 new classes to deal with, in addition to a 40-way switch statement to create them.
- A complex function might have a lot of state variables that would get very messy if passed between different functions as parameters. In this case you could reasonably make an argument that the code is simpler and easier to follow if you keep everything in a single large function (although as Mark rightly points out this could also be a candidate for turning into a class to encapsulate both the logic and state).
- Sometimes smaller or larger functions have performance advantages (perhaps because of inlining or JIT reasons as Frank mentions). This is highly implementation dependent, but it can make a difference - make sure you benchmark!

So basically, ***use common sense***, stick to small function sizes in most instances but don't be dogmatic about it if you have a genuinely good reason to make an unusually big function.

Comment: There's a technical/perf reason for short methods, too: JIT cache hits. Many smaller, reusable methods are more likely to have been called before. Oh and an extra diag benefit, StackTraces are more focused on the logic that went pop.

Comment: "use common sense" is the most important advice

Comment: One should be aware that this heuristic will result in complaints of "ravioli code" due to the depth of the stack in breakpoints, when debugging.

Comment: @FrankHileman I will take ravioli over spaghetti any day when writing code

Comment: @Snowman: these choices are not mutually exclusive... short stack depths without spaghetti is the ideal. Deep stack depths, with spaghetti on the side?

Comment: Arguments against your top two (scrolling and keeping things in your head): it's much easier to scroll a very small amount than have to jump back and forth between the calling method and called method, which may be quite a distance apart, especially when there are many called mathods

Comment: YMMV but I find that my IDE (Eclipse) has a very useful "Open Declaration" feature (F3) which makes navigating between related methods just as easy as scrolling.

Comment: The concept of `Single Responsibility` should drive this decision too.

Answer (score 41):

While I agree with other's comments when they said there's no hard rule about right LOC number, I bet if we look back at the projects we've looked at in the past and identify every function above, let's say 150 lines of code, I'm guessing we would come to a consensus that 9 out of 10 of those functions break SRP (and very likely OCP as well), have too many local variables, too much control flow and are generally hard to read and maintain.

So while LOC may not be a direct indicator of bad code, it is certainly a decent indirect indicator that certain function could be written better.

On my team I fell into the position of a lead and for whatever reason, people seem to be listening to me. What I generally settled on is to tell the team that while there's no absolute limit, any function more 50 lines of code should at a minimum raise a red flag during code review, so that we take a second look at it and re-evaluate it for complexity and SRP/OCP violations. After that second look, we might leave it alone or we might change it, but at least it makes people think about these things.

Comment: This seems sensible - LOC doesn't mean anything with respect to complexity or code quality, but it can be a good marker for the possibility that things should be refactored.

Comment: "come to a consensus that 9 out of 10 of those functions break SRP" - I disagree, I am pretty sure 10 out of 10 of those functions will break it ;-)

Comment: +1 for raising a flag during code review: in other words, not a hard and fast rule, but let's discuss this code as a group.

Answer (score 23):

I stepped into a project which hasn't had any care about coding guidelines. When I look into the code I sometimes find classes with more than 6000 lines of code and less than 10 methods. This is a horror scenario when you have to fix bugs.

A general rule of how big a method should be at maximum is sometimes not so good. I like the rule by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob): "Methods should be small, smaller than small". I try to use this rule all the time. I am trying to keep my methods simple and small by clarifying that my method does only one thing and nothing more.

Comment: I don't see  why a 6000 line function is harder to debug than a shorter one... Unless it has other problems too (eg. repetition)

Comment: It has nothing to do with debugging.. its about complexity and maintainability. How you would extend or change a 6000 lines method done by another one?

Comment: @Calmarius the difference is usually that 6000 line functions tend to contain local variables which were declared very far away (visually), making it difficult for the programmer to build up the mental context required to have high confidence about the code.  Can you be sure about how a variable is initialised and built up at any given point?  Are you sure nothing is going to mess with your variable after you've set it on line 3879?  On the other hand, with 15 line methods, you can be sure.

Comment: @DanielB I wouldn't touch any variable before I know how it is used. So I would search for all occurrences of it in its scope to see which other functions and statements alter it. I'd also refactor the code to bring down all variables into the smallest scope possible.

Comment: @Smokefoot I would factor out repetitive patterns into single functions/macros etc. If the function isn't a repetitive mess, there is 90% chance the reason for its length is a huge switch, which mean you probably need to add just a new case. 

If you explode the 6000 lines into 60 100 line functions, you make the next fellow's job even harder because now he'll need to scroll and jump around many source files to put things together in his mind.

Comment: @Calmarius agreed, but both of those statements are an argument against 6000 LOC functions.

Comment: A local variable in a 600 line method is essentially a global variable.

Comment: @Smokefoot I've seen 6000 line 'methods' (perhaps procedure is a better name).  I've seen it being extended by adding 20 lines of code and by adding/changing the compound condition of one of the 17 if statements that more or less fit the issue at hand.  I would not recommend this approach though.  Step by step I'm trying to educate others to imho better ways.

Answer (score 16):

I'll just throw in yet another quote.

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for
>   machines to execute
>
> -- Harold Abelson

It is very improbable that functions that grow to 100-200 follow this rule

Comment: Except when they contain a switch.

Comment: or construct an object based on the results of a database query that returns dozens of fields per row in the resultset...

Comment: Database results are certainly an acceptable exception - plus they're usually "dumb" statements that populate some instance of a class (or whatever), rather than logic than needs to be followed.

Answer (score 12):

**It depends**, seriously, there really isn't a solid answer to this question because the language you are work with matters, the five to fifteenth lines mentioned [in this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133406/2471) might work for C# or Java, but in other languages it doesn't give you much to work with. Likewise, depending upon the domain you are working in, you might find yourself writing code setting values in a large data structure. With some data structures you might have tens of elements that you need to set, should you break things out in to separate functions just because your function is running long?

As others have noted, the best rule of thumb is that a function should be a single logical entity that handles a single task. If you try to enforce draconian rules that say that functions can't be longer than *n* lines and you make that value too small your code will grow harder to read as developers try and use fancy tricks to get around the rule. Likewise, if you set it too high it will be a non-issue and can lead to bad code though laziness. Your best bet is to just conduct code reviews to ensure that functions are handling a single task and leave it at that.

Answer (score 11):

It is not about number of lines, it is about SRP.
According to this principle, your method should do one and only one thing.

If your method does this AND this AND this OR that => it is probably doing to much. Try to look at this method and analyse: "here I get this data, sort it and get elements I need" and "here I process these elements" and "here I finally combine them in order to get the result". These "blocks" should be refactored to other methods.

If you simply follow SRP most of your method will be small and with clear intention.

It is not correct to say "this method is > 20 lines so it is wrong". It can be *an indication* that something *may be* wrong with this method, no more.

You may have a 400 lines switch in a method (often happens in telecom), and it is still single responsibility and it is perfectly OK.

Comment: Large switch statements, output formatting, definitions of hashes/dictionaries that should be hardcoded rather than flexible in some database, this often happens, and is perfectly fine. As long as the logic is devided, then you're all good. A large method could prompt you to think 'should I split this'. The answer could very well be 'no, this is fine as it is' (or yes, this is an absolute mess)

Comment: What does "SRP" mean?

Comment: SRP stands for [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and states that every class (or method) should have only one responsibility. It is related to cohesion and coupling. If you follow the SRP, your classes (or methods) will have good cohesion, but coupling may be increased because you end up with more classes (or methods).

Comment: +1 for SRP.  By writing cohesive functions, one can then more easily combine them in functional style to achieve more complex results.  In the end it's better that a function be made up of three other functions that got glued together than to have a single function doing three discrete, even if somehow related, things.

Comment: Yea but what is a single responsibility. Its just a concept created in your head. If you need 400 lines for a single responsibility your concept of single responsibility is probably way different then mine

Answer (score 10):

I think one problem here is that the length of a function says nothing about its complexity. LOC (Lines of Code) are a bad instrument to measure anything.

A method should not be overly complex, but there are scenarios where a long method can be easily maintained. Note that the following example does not say it could not be split into methods, just that the methods would not change the maintainability.

for example a handler for incoming data can have a large switch statement and then simple code per case. I have such code - managing incoming data from a feed. 70 (!) numerically coded handlers. Now, one will  say "use constants" - yes, except the API does not provide them and I like to stay close to "source" here. Methods? Sure - just sadly all of them deal with data from the same 2 huge structures. No benefit in splitting them off except maybe having more methods (readability). The code is intrinsically not complex - one switch, depending on a field. Then every case has a block that parses x elements of data and publishes them. No maintenance nightmare. There is one repeating" if condition that determiens whether a field has data (pField = pFields [x], if pField->IsSet() { blabla }) - same pretty much for every field...

Replace that with a much smaller routine containing nested loop and a lot of real switching statements and a huge method can be more easy to maintain than one smaller one.

So, sorry, LOC is not a good measurement to start with. If anything, then complexity / decision points should be used.

Comment: LOC are a fine tool to use for the one area where they provide a relevant measure - very large projects where they can be used to help give estimates to how long a similar project might take to be completed. Beyond that, people tend to worry about them too much.

Comment: Right. It is not like LOC does not depe3nd soemtimes on how expressive I write the code, on hformatting rquirements etc. LOC are totally unsuitable and somethin that MBA's witout any experience use. Only. You are free to put yourself into the list of people not understanding why LOC are a bad measurement, but clearly that will not make you look as someone to listen to.

Comment: Please review what I said again, I noted that LOC are a good tool only for one area of measurement and use (i.e. extremely large projects where they can be used for estimation). Anything smaller than the large scale and they use most if not all value for anything beyond quick sound bites in meeting to keep people happy. They are kind of like trying to use light years to measure how fair the coffee shop is from the office, sure you can do it, but the measurement is useless. But when you need to discuss distances between stars they work great.

Comment: +1 a function should have all the code it needs to perform the function. It should do one thing and one thing only -- but if that takes a 1000 lines of code then so be it.

Comment: I have written handlers for incoming socket data and yes, they can require a thousand or more LOC. However, I can count on one hand the number of times I have needed to do that and cannot count the numbers of times it was _not_ the appropriate way to code.

Answer (score 7):

If I find long method, I could bet this method is not properly unit-tested or most time it hasn't unit test at all. If you start doing TDD you will never build up 100-lines methods with 25 different responsibilities and 5 nested loops. 
Tests oblige you constantly refactor your mess and write uncle Bob's clean code.

Answer (score 7):

I've been in this crazy racket, one way or another, since 1970.

In all that time, with two exceptions that I'll get to in a moment, I have NEVER seen a well-designed "routine" (method, procedure, function, subroutine, whatever) that NEEDED to be more than one printed page (about 60 lines) long.  The vast majority of them were quite a bit short, on the order of 10-20 lines.

I have, however, seen a LOT of "stream-of-consciousness" code, written by people who apparently never heard of modularization.

The two exceptions were very much special cases.  One is actually a class of exception cases, that I lump together: large finite-state automata, implemented as big ugly switch statements, usually because there isn't a cleaner way to implement them.  These things usually show up in automated test equipment, parsing data logs from the device under test.

The other was the photon torpedo routine from the Matuszek-Reynolds-McGehearty-Cohen STARTRK game, written in CDC 6600 FORTRAN IV.  It had to parse the command line, then simulate the flight of each torpedo, with perturbations, check the interaction between the torpedo and each kind of thing it could hit, and oh by the way simulate recursion to do 8-way connectivity on chains of novae from torpedoing a star that was next to other stars.

Comment: +1 for the "get off my lawn" vibe I get from this answer. Also, from personal experience from before OOP languages were widespread.

Comment: It isn't so much "get off my lawn" as an observation that I have seen a LOT of crap code over the years, and it seems to be getting WORSE.

Comment: My boss has this habit of writing methods several hundred lines long, often with several levels of nested ifs. He also uses partial classes (.NET) to "break" a class into several files so he can claim that he's keeping them short.  Those are only two things I have to deal with.  Been doing this for about 25 years, and I can confirm that things ARE getting worse.  And now time for me to go back into that mess.

Answer (score 3):

Do the authors mean the same thing by "function" and "routine"?  Typically when I say "function" I mean a subroutine/operation which returns a value and "procedure" for one which does not (and whose call becomes a single statement).  This is not a common distinction throughout SE in the real world but I have seen it in user texts.

Either way, there is no right answer to this.  Preference for one or the other (if there is a preference at all) is something I would expect to be very different between languages, projects, and organizations; just as it is with all code conventions.

The one bit I would add is that the whole "long operations are no more error-prone than short operations" assertion is not strictly true.  In addition to the fact that more code equals more potential error space, it is blindingly obvious that breaking code into segments will make errors both easier to avoid and easier to locate.  Otherwise there would be no reason to break code into pieces at all, save repetition.  But this is perhaps true only if said segments are documented well enough that you can determine the results of an operation call without reading through or tracing the actual code (design-by-contract based on specifications rather than concrete dependency between areas of code).

Additionally, if you want longer operations to work well, you might want to adopt stricter code conventions to support them.  Tossing a return statement in the middle of an operation might be fine for a short operation, but in longer operations this can create a large section of code which is conditional but not obviously conditional on a quick read-through (just for one example).

So I would think that which style is less likely to be a bug-filled nightmare would depend in large part on what conventions you adhere to for the rest of your code.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no absolute rules about method's length, but the following rules have been useful:

1. Function's primary purpose is to find the return value. There is no other reason for it's existence. Once that reason is fullfilled, no other code should be inserted to it. This necessarily keeps functions small. Calling other functions should only be done if it makes finding the return value easier.
2. On the other hand, interfaces should be small. This means you either have large number of classes, or you have large functions -- one of the two is going to happen once you start to have enough code to do anything significant. Big programs can have both.

Comment: What about side effects - writing to a file, resetting status, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you shouldn't have to use scrollbar to read your function. As soon as you need to move scrollbar, it take a few more time to understand how work the function.

Accordingly, it depends of usual programming environment of your team work (screen resolution, editor, font size, etc...). In 80's, it was 25 lines and 80 columns. Now, on my editor, I display nearly 50 lines. Number of columns I display did not change since I split my screen in two to display two files at times.

In brief, it depends of setup of your coworkers.

Comment: Wasn't it rather 24 lines that time? I'm thinking of 3270 or 9750 terminals, where the 25th was the status line. And the terminal emulations followed this.

Comment: some systems/editors had 40 or 50 lines from the start. These days 150 lines is not uncommon and 200+ is doable, so that's not really a good metric.

Comment: I use my screen in portrait orientation, I can see 200 lines of code at once.

Comment: and if I don't use any line breaks to break up my lines I can code a 5000 line method in a single line...

Answer (score 1):

I think [TomTom's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133408/31260) came close to how I feel about it.

More and more I find myself going on cyclomatic complexity rather than lines.

I normally aim for no more than one control structure per method, with the exception of however many loops it takes to handle a multi-dimensional array.

I sometimes find myself putting one-line ifs in switch cases because for some reason these tend to be cases where splitting it out hinders rather than helps.

Note that I do not count guard logic against this limit.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity has been shown, on large quantities of real production code, to be VERY strongly correlated with raw SLOC, making the computation of cyclomatic complexity a total waste of time, energy, and clock cycles.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I'm talking about per method, not overall.  Sure, in the big picture it's highly correlated--the question is how to split that code up into methods.  10 methods of 100 lines or 100 methods of 10 lines will still have the same overall SLOC and complexity but the former is going to be a lot harder to work with.

Comment: so am I.  The correlation study looked at LOTS of code, and LOTS of routines.  (It was one of the big public repositories.)

Answer (score -1):

In OOP all things object and there are these features:

1. Polymorphism
2. Abstraction
3. Inheritance

When you observance these rules then your methods is usually small but don't exist any rule for small or very small (e.g  2-3 line) rules.
A benefit of small method(small unit eg method or function) are:

1. better readable
2. maintain better
3. fixed bug better
4. changes better